# SMTP not working on Code Igniter when I deployed the code on production

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl, smtp

I created a emailer using smtp gmail.  My code works on development, but when I deployed it to production it doesn't work.

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; 




A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:
to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA
data:
```

I encountered this issue on development before and the fix was just to add this line.
`$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");` but it's not working on production.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection timed out` means, that it could not even connect to the server.
If this works in development, but not in production you have maybe a firewall in front of the production system to protect it, and this blocks the access.